# Android - apply transitions to dynamically created views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-transitions

In my Android activity I have a TextView on the top which stays put throughout and below that a RelativeLayout which is the container to my dynamic views. In linear layout I add a LinearLayoutCompat object which has multiple TextViews. When any of the TextViews is clicked, the entire LinearLayoutCompat object is removed and a new one is added with a new set of TextViews. Now I want to add transitions to addition (slide in from left) and removal (slide out below) of LinearLayoutCompat views. 
I have tried creating my own LinearLayoutCompat class named LinearLay and overriding onAttatchedToWindow() method to set off transitions (has been commented out) but is just doesn't show any transitions(I tested just for addition of view initially).

**My Activity**

```
    public class VegOptions extends AppCompatActivity{

        protected DBSource vegDBSource;
        private Cursor cursor;
        LayoutInflater li ;
        View v ;
        ViewGroup dataConPt ;
        Slide mslide;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            setContentView(R.layout.veg_option);
            vegDBSource = new DBSource(VegOptions.this);
            li = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.veg_option, null);
            dataConPt = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.dataCont);
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mslide = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        }
            disp("VEGCAT");
        }

        private void disp(String COL)
        {   vegDBSource.open();
            cursor = vegDBSource.getInfo(COL);
            LinearLayoutCompat linearLayoutCompat = defaultPage(cursor, COL);
            if(linearLayoutCompat != null)
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(dataConPt, mslide);
            }
                dataConPt.removeAllViews();
                dataConPt.addView(linearLayoutCompat);
            }
        }

        public LinearLayoutCompat defaultPage(Cursor mCursor, String COL) {
            if(mCursor==null || mCursor.getCount() == 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You're in a mood for " + COL + " !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return null;
            }
            else {
                LinearLayoutCompat layout = new LinearLayoutCompat(this);
                LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                layout.setLayoutParams(params);
                layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutCompat.VERTICAL);
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    final AppCompatTextView defaultText = new AppCompatTextView(this);
                    defaultText.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_TYPES)));
                    defaultText.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.TextFontMain);
                    defaultText.setTextSize(30);
                    defaultText.setPadding(0, 30, 0, 30);
                    defaultText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    defaultText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            String choice = defaultText.getText().toString();
                            disp(choice);

                        }
                    });
                    layout.addView(defaultText);
                    mCursor.moveToNext();
                } while (mCursor.isAfterLast() == false);
                return layout;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            vegDBSource.close();
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
    }
```

I was able to apply transitions to the removal and addition of the views by creating an object of Slide class (android.transition) and using `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(dataContPt, mSlide)` which automatically applies slide transition to the change in views. The problem here now is that in removal of existing views and addition of new views, there is overlap. I want the existing views to be removed first and then new views be added. Is there any way I can introduce this kind of delay ?

Comment: in your LinearLayout in xml try this 
   
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"

Comment: please see update

Comment: Where is the `beginDelayedTransition()` part?

Comment: I just updated the code too